# I have a problem with styling in Vuetify, i need 'messages' to be black but its blue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have v text field and when i type the 'messages' will have a small tranformation and its turn to color blue. I want the messages to be black.

```
<v-text-field solo
   mask="###" 
   label="Bredd" 
   id="secondNumber" 
   v-model="secondNumber"
   messages='Avrunda till meter'
></v-text-field><br>
```

The messages turn blue when i start typing but i want it to be black.

I have tried to overwrite with: messages{ color:black,} and i have tried to grab it to a class but nothing works.

I want to change the messages in css.

Comment: I solved it , used  color="purple darken-2" abow it

Comment: Please consider answering your own question